# How can I escape spaces in a path to file I'm passing to PHP-cli (on Windows)

Tags: php, windows, cmd

Let me start by saying just how much I truly hate PHP on Windows.

With that out of the way, all I'm trying to do is pass a file to PHP, because the PHP msi installer didnt work (clearly they dont care too much about PHP working on windows either), I've just used the zipped files.

I have a file which needs to be passed into php, and two parameters which need to be passed to the file, so i launch my script like this from cmd:

```
c:\php\php.exe c:\my_location\Myscript.php t:\test AF7
```

The above works just fine (after a lot of messing about), the last two parameters are passed to the PHP script and can handle spaces if they are escaped by double quotes and I use escapeshellarg() within the script.

However someone has decided to install my script itself in a path containing spaces and I have no idea how to get round it:

e.g if I tried:

```
c:\php\php.exe "c:\my location\myscript.php" t:\test AF7
```

It comes back with the error "Could not open input file: C:\my"

Note: I've also tried escaping with a '^' but this doesnt seem to work either

Here is the layout of my script for clarity:

```
Class Myscript 
{
    public static function convert($classfile, $par1, $par2)
    {
        //code here
    }
}
call_user_func_array(array('Myscript', 'convert'), $argv);
```

How can I handle this correctly, you're help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: As requested I have updated my question with the exact error message (probably should have included it to begin with).